# VBA Very Slow Performance using objects with scripting dictionary

Tags: performance, vba, excel, hash-map

I have a simple code that loops through a text file to fix a few things in it and I use mostly dictionaries to find and handle the adjustment. However, with larger files (about 30K lines) it seems to get exponentially slower in a specific line of a loop. This line shouldn't be so slow because it just has to access an element specified and alter value. Anyone knows why this is happening ?

I can't figure out why that is happening and how to go around without a huge performance loss.

```
For i = 0 To tags.Count - 1
    If tags.Items(i)(2) = 0 Then   'This is the slow part. I need the validation for my case usage.
        linhas(CStr(i)) = 1
    End If
Next i
```

This is the full code simplified:

```vb
Sub ajusta_ofx_teste() 'macro para converter arquivos ofx em xml
    
    Dim my_file As Integer
    Dim text_line As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim linhas As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim tags As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim nfso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dados_tag(4) As Variant

    strofx = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=False)
    
    'Open file_name For Input As #my_file
    Set arquivo = fso.OpenTextFile(strofx, ForReading)
    
    L = 10000
    f = 0
    i = 0      'Define o número de linhas com Tag
    loops = 0  'Define a linha do arquivo sendo lida
    ntags = 0
    achou = 0
    
    While Not arquivo.AtEndOfStream
        'Line Input #my_file, text_line
        text_line = arquivo.ReadLine
        
        If i > 100000 Then Stop
        x = InStr(1, text_line, "<") 'Marca o início do Tag
        
        'Save only lines with Tag in "tag" dictionary.
        If x > 0 Then
        linhas.Add CStr(i), text_line
        
            If Mid(text_line, x + 1, 1) <> "/" Then

                ntags = ntags + 1
                fim_tag_i = InStr(1, text_line, ">")
                dados_tag(0) = i                                       'Tag line number
                dados_tag(1) = Mid(text_line, x, fim_tag_i - x + 1)    'Tag name
                dados_tag(2) = 0                                       'Registry used after - I removed the part of the code that fills it depending on the tag.
                dados_tag(3) = 0
                
                chave = Format(ntags, "000000") & dados_tag(1)         'chave = "Key"
                tags.Add chave, dados_tag
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If

        loops = loops + 1
        If loops > 100000 Then Stop 'saida de emergencia do loop
    Wend
    nlinhas = i
    arquivo.Close

    For i = 0 To tags.Count - 1
        If tags.Items(i)(2) = 0 Then   'This is the slow part. I need the validation for my case usage.
            linhas(CStr(i)) = 1
        End If
    Next i

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set nfso = Nothing
End Sub
```

The text file can be downloaded here: [test.ofx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/133p_FGJ3DMJQXNj7VyiXro_TjwtRVKU0/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 2):

##### Speed issue

`tags.Items` does a copy of the array of items. So, you are copying that array 32821 times which of course is slow.

Replace this:

```
For i = 0 To tags.Count - 1
    If tags.Items(i)(2) = 0 Then   'This is the slow part. I need the validation for my case usage.
        linhas(CStr(i)) = 1
    End If
Next i
```

with this:

```
Dim arrItems() As Variant: arrItems = tags.Items
For i = 0 To tags.Count - 1
    If arrItems(i)(2) = 0 Then
        linhas(CStr(i)) = 1
    End If
Next i
```

##### Other issues

Best practice is to have `Option Explicit` at the top of each code module. This forces you to declare all variables. In your code there are 11 undeclared variables which are all defaulted to `Variant`:
strofx, arquivo, L, f, loops, ntags, achou, x, fim_tag_i, chave, nlinhas

Imagine having `Dim cake as Long` in your code and then somewhere later you can do a typing mistake and use `cakes` instead of `cake`. Without `Option Explicit` your code will compile and you won't even know why it's not working correctly.

To make this into a habit, turn on 'Require Variable Declaration' under Tools/Options: [image: option]

Use `Stop` only for debugging. Never for production code.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the great for the great answer!
I always thought that ".items" was a property and not a whole copy being made. It seems i have lots of codes to improve haha.

Also thanks for the tip regarding declarations. I'm always lazy to declare everything but you are correct. 

Now the code takes only 15 seconds to run in comparison to more than 15 minutes before (i never waited until the end so a don't know the exact time it would take.).

Comment: @KE_1234 You are correct when you say that ```.Items``` is a property. However, this particular property returns an array. In VBA, when you assign an array, a copy is made by default. For example: ```arr2 = arr1``` makes a copy of the ```arr1``` array.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question regarding speed is answered by @CristianBuse.  In addition to the excellent recommendations that came along with his answer, I wanted to suggest one more improvement un-related to performance...

Your code opens a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `TextStream` object and does not guarantee the destruction of both if an error should occur.  Even though the provided code is "the full code simplified", I'm suspecting the *full code* has the same issue.  So, rather than:

```
Sub ajusta_ofx_teste()
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set arquivo = fso.OpenTextFile(strofx, ForReading)    
    
    '... preparing for the While-Wend loop

    While Not arquivo.AtEndOfStream
        '... loop code
    Wend
    nlinhas = i
    arquivo.Close
    
    '... the 'slow part'
    
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

It would be better to guarantee that `arquivo.Close` and `Set fso = Nothing` are both executed in the event that an error is encountered.  To do so, the code could be re-organized as follows:

```
Option Explicit 'The importance of ALWAYS declaring this Option cannot be overstated

Sub ajusta_ofx_teste() 'macro para converter arquivos ofx em xml
    Dim strofx As Variant
    strofx = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=False)
    
    If strofx = False Then 'User does not select a file
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim arquivo As TextStream
On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Set arquivo = fso.OpenTextFile(strofx, ForReading)
    
    ProcessTextStream arquivo
    
ErrorExit:
    If Not arquivo Is Nothing Then
        arquivo.Close
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessTextStream (ByVal arquivo As TextStream)
    '... Declare necessary variables, e.g., linhas, i, tags, ...
    
    While Not arquivo.AtEndOfStream
        '... loop code
    Wend
    nlinhas = i

    'The recommended code for the code formerly known as 'the slow part'
    Dim arrItems() As Variant: arrItems = tags.Items
    For i = 0 To tags.Count - 1
        If arrItems(i)(2) = 0 Then
            linhas(CStr(i)) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Now, if an error occurs during `ProcessStream`, the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, and the `TextStream` are properly cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. What happens if i don't properly close the txt stream? I thought vba would close it automatically. Will it just remain as trash in the Memory until the next restart ?

Comment: The suggestion falls under the category of a best/better practice.  It matters more if you opened a file for writing - in a scenario where an error occurs while writing to a file (resulting in skipping the call to `Close`).  If the code later tries to open the same file for writing using a different `TextStream` object - a 'Permission denied' error is generated.  I tested Reading a file using the same scenario. It executes successfully whether `Close` is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you to @Cristian Buse for the clarification and answer.

The code supplied works perfectly but i went with a slight different approach.
I tested both and this last one is a bit faster.

```
For Each strkey In tags.Keys()
    If tags(strkey)(2) = 0 Then
        linhas(tags(strkey)(0)) = linhas(CStr(tags(strkey)(0))) & Replace(tags(strkey)(1), "<", "</")
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next strkey
```

The total run time was 16 seconds with Cristian's method and 14 seconds with this method.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thanks for posting this code.  It's a good idea to summarise which changes you made, and why - a self-answer ought to review the code, just like any other answer.